# Is it possible to access tags inside a pom.xml file using mvn command?

Tags: maven, jenkins

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <twilio-version>6.3.0</twilio-version>
</properties>
```

Suppose I have the above setup in my pom.xml, is it possible to grab say the java version from it?

My idea is to have Jenkins/JenkinsFile to run some say 'maven GRAB_PARAM PARAM_NAME' method and use whatever the value to setup its build environment.

So my JenkinsFile would be:

```
node {
    stage 'Clean Up'
    deleteDir()

    stage 'Env Setup'
    def mvnHome = tool '3.0.3'
    env.JAVA_HOME = THE_MVN_COMMAND_THAT_CAN_GRAB_VERSION_FROM_POM

    stage 'Compile/Package'
    checkout scm
    sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn clean install -DskipTests"
}
```

I also wanna use this so I can easily grab the build version from previous build etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the Maven Help Plugin and its [`evaluate`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/evaluate-mojo.html) Mojo:

> Evaluates Maven expressions given by the user in an interactive mode.

```
mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=java.version
```

With versions up to 2.2, this has the unfortunate situation of printing a lot of information with it, that can be filtered out by piping the result to `| findstr /v "[INFO]"` on Windows, or `| grep -v "[INFO]"` or Unix-line systems.

Starting with version 3.0.0, you can use

```
mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=java.version -Doutput=result.txt
```

to redirect the output of the evaluation to a file. As of today, 3.0.0 is still in a SNAPSHOT state, so you can add a plugin repository to your settings or POM, allowing snapshots, and pointing to Apache snapshot repo at `https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/`.

Answer (score 2):

The [maven-help-plugin and its goal evaluate](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/evaluate-mojo.html) is probably what you need.

Something like

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.2:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version
```

will output the project version.